# C# 8.0 using Range for multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, range

In C# 8.0, why can I use range on single dimensional arrays:

```
var oneDim = new int[5];
var oneDimSlice = oneDim[2..4];
```

But can not use it on multi dimensional arrays ?

```
var twoDim = new int[5, 5];
var twoDimSlice = twoDim[2..4, 2..4];
```

Comment: Need to ask c# specification team about this,

Answer (score 5):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes

> Array has more nuanced behavior. Single dimension arrays support both
>   indices and ranges. Multi-dimensional arrays don't. The indexer for a
>   multi-dimensional array has multiple parameters, not a single
>   parameter. Jagged arrays, also referred to as an array of arrays,
>   support both ranges and indexers.

so the answer is no, but it is possible to do it with jagged arrays if you are interested.