# How to use the from end indexing syntax for multidimensional arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, c#-8.0

I would like to use the C# 8 from end indexing syntax for a two-dimensional array. How can this be done, or is it not supported? I have an external source of indexes for the array, and access it in the following fashion:

```
(int, int)[] indexes = new (int, int)[1] { (0, 1) } /* GetIndexes() */;
int[,] array = new int[1,1] /* GetArray() */;

foreach((int i, int j) in indexes)
{
    _ = array[i, array.GetLength(1) - j]; // Current
    _ = array[i, ^j]; // What I have in mind
}
```

But what I have in mind gives me the compiler error "[CS0029](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/roslyn.query?appId=roslyn&k=k(CS0029)): Cannot implicilty convert type 'System.Index' to 'int'."

This is related to array slicing syntax since they are both array operations and were released in the same language version. However, they are still different operations and one's presence is not fundamentally dependent on the other's.

*Thanks*

Comment: can you paste a **working** code snippet that causes above exception?

Comment: found similiar question [C# 8.0 using Range for multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55065816/c-sharp-8-0-using-range-for-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: I've edited the question to supply a working example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#implicit-index-support) for the Index and Range syntaxes, the language will only automatically add an indexer taking an `Index` if:

> - The type is Countable.
> - The type has an accessible instance indexer which takes a single `int` as the argument.
> - The type does not have an accessible instance indexer which takes an `Index` as the first parameter. The `Index` must be the only parameter
>   or the remaining parameters must be optional.

A 2D array does not fulfil the second of these requirements, and even if it did, an indexer taking *one* `Index` as parameter isn't what you want. Searching through the proposal, it appears that they didn't consider multi-dimensional arrays all that much.

For now, you can write your own extension method on `T[,]` that takes 2 `Index`s:

```
static class ArrayExtensions {
    public static T Get<T>(this T[,] arr, Index x, Index y)
        => arr[
            x.IsFromEnd ? arr.GetLength(0) - x.Value : x.Value,
            y.IsFromEnd ? arr.GetLength(1) - y.Value : y.Value
        ];
}
```

Do note that if you have a jagged array (`int[][]`), index syntax *does* work.